# How best to explain partial order over vectors?

Tags: notation, terminology, order-theory

I have the following notational issue:

Given a vector space $\mathbf{V}$, I have a partial order such that for all $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w} \in \mathbf{V}$:

iff for all components $v_i$ of $\mathbf{v}$ and  $w_i$ of $\mathbf{w}$
$$v_i\leq w_i$$

then

$$\mathbf{v} \leq \mathbf{w}$$

Is there a  well known way of stating this partial order ?

Comment: Presumably it is a vector space $\mathbf V$.  I think you have stated it well.  You might use a different symbol for the comparison between vectors like $\mathbf v \preceq \mathbf w$ using \preceq

Comment: The way you stated it seems clear to me.

Comment: The problem is not clarity, it is the space it will occupy to mention. I was wondering if there is just a name for this, so i could write  we have "xxx" partial order on $\mathbf{V}$, and we denote it with $\leq$

Comment: I'd say the word "component-wise" would describe this well, but you should give the fully written out definition the first time you use it, and then you can use your chosen symbol, or that term, thereafter.

Comment: You also need to specify a basis in $\mathbf{V}$ for this to work. The components depend on a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had not heard of this concept before, but searching for "componentwise partial order" brought up the "[product order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_order)", which seems to be what you want.

I'm not an order theorist, but if you didn't know of a name for this offhand, your audience may not know this definition of "product order", so it would be good to give the definition in whatever you are writing, anyway.